# Next.js Image can not be inside Link?

Tags: next.js

I have this structure:

```js
    return (
        <nav className={`${isTransparent ? 'transparent' : ''}`}>
            <Link href={'/'}>
                <Image src={'/logo.svg'} width={68} height={50} alt="logo" />
            </Link>
```

and got this error, what is wrong?

```
next-dev.js?3515:24 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `ForwardRef(LinkComponent)`.
    at Image (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/image.js:19:22)
    at LinkComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js:92:23)
    at nav
    at Navbar (webpack-internal:///./tikexModule/components/Navbar/index.tsx:27:31)
```

Image can not child of Link?

---

OK, I put `<Image>` inside `<a>`, it dismiss warning, but why? Could you explain?

```js
<Link href="/">
<a>
    <Image src="/logo.svg" width={68} height={50} alt="logo" />
</a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Image can be inside link. You have syntax errors. Do not put the `li` element inside the Link, it belongs to the `ul`.

Comment: outside there is `ul`,`li` should be right under `ul`?

Comment: Yes, because the `li` is `ul`'s son, not `Link`'s son. You can put the link inside the `li`.

Comment: actually warning is reased on the other section <Link> <Image>, not <ul><li>. Better I remove, it only misslead.

Comment: OK, I put <Image> inside <a>, it dismiss warning, but why? Could you explain?

Comment: What's the warning? You should not use an `a` inside a `Link` because they have the same purpose. Also an `a` needs at least one attribute:`href`

Comment: According to the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-functional-component): _"If the child of `Link` is a functional component, in addition to using `passHref`, you must wrap the component in `React.forwardRef`"_. Adding the `<a>` around the `Link` removes this requirement, hence the warning no longer occurs.

Comment: But why child of a `Link` is fucntional componenet, it is not. It is an `Image`.